# knitr: how to print the visible parts of the expression in a custom code chunk using engine_output()?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I am creating a custom code chunk which rewrites the expressions that a user passes into the code block into valid R code, and then execute the analysis. Aside from the rewriting of the R expression that the user inputs, the goal is for the code chunk to work as a regular code chunk

I then execute the result and store it in a variable, which I am trying to output. I am running into two issues here:

1. It prints invisible variables
2. `knit_print` and `engine_output` do not seem to work with each other i.e. I want the output such as dataframes to be printed in the table format but I am not able to get it to work.

An example of what I am trying to do would be something like:

````
```{r}
custom_engine <- function(options) {
  c = options$code
  pasted <- paste(c, collapse = "\n")
  code <- parse(text = pasted)

  result = lapply(code, eval, envir = .GlobalEnv)
  knit_print(result)
  engine_output( options, code = c, out = NULL )
}

knitr::knit_engines$set(mmm = custom_engine)
```


```{r}
speed_data <- data.frame( 
    speed = rlnorm(100, log(200), 1), 
    device = sample(c("smartphone", "laptop", "tablet"), 100, TRUE, prob= c(0.1, 0.65, 0.25)) 
  )

median = median(speed_data$speed)
iqr = IQR(speed_data$speed, na.rm=TRUE)
```


```{mmm}
result_analysis <- speed_data %>% 
  filter(speed < median + 3 * iqr & speed > 10) %>% 
  filter(device != "smartphone")

result_analysis
```
````

I would like the code above to print the table once, and in the default knit_print() format that RMarkdown does.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: I am curious to better understand your use case here. I don't see yet the difference between your custom engine and a regular R code chunk. It seems like you are trying to reproduce R engine behavior in a way. Better understanding your need here would help me give better advice, maybe on solutions that you did not think of yet. I am not sure to understand why `out = NULL` meaning you have not output... Currently running the Rmd example prints nothing as output for chunk. I only get the echo of chunk. However, I get some printing in the console during rendering, is this what is intended ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. This is a simplified example, but we are working on a project where the syntax needs to be more flexible than the current R syntax. So we first rewrite the users' R code into actually valid and executable R code, and then execute it in R. So we want the code chunk to reproduce R engine behavior, but only for the re-written code.
I had `out = NULL` because I was getting two outputs, but I think it's partially because I don't understand the functions `engine_output()` and `knit_print()` very well.

Comment: For the example above, what I want is to print the data frame, which is returned visibly, in the document and not in the console. I am not sure how to go about this.